# How to express a statement in a Venn diagram?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having issue drawing this statement onto a Venn diagram:

$$(A\cup B)'\cup (B∪C)'\cup (C\cup A)'$$

(complements are relative to $U$, the universe). The blank diagram:

[image]

#### Update

Is this answer correct?

[image: answer]

Comment: Does that notation mean the complement relative to U?

Comment: yes that what it means

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to do $(A \cup B)'$? Do each term seperately at first. Then all areas combined are the union. Let us know if you don't know how to do $(A \cup B)'$.

Comment: I think this is the answer, is that correct? http://s28.postimg.org/o5wkf7w7x/38fa_R.gif

Comment: Looks good to me.